# Using ratio find the difference of two numbers will be

Tags: ratio

Two number are in the ratio 2:5 and become 4:7 when 5 is added to each of them.Twice the difference of two numbers will be.

Answer (score 4):

You have:

$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{2}{5}$$

$$\frac{x+5}{y+5}=\frac{4}{7}$$

Hint:

Think substitution to find $x$ and $y$, find their  difference, and thus find twice their difference.